# Open and run commands on cmd from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

A similar question was asked several times on SO, and usually the answer is one of:

- run the same command on PowerShell because it's also there
- run `cmd` and then the commands
- invoke `cmd` passing `/c`

and a few other things that I've already tried. But my problem is: I have a specific program (`cntkpy34.bat`) that **refuses** to run on PowerShell. That is, with any of solutions like above I still get "Please execute this script from inside a regular Windows command prompt."

So what I *really* want is to invoke a new `cmd.exe` window and run the commands on it. How can this be achieved in a PowerShell script?

**EDIT**: inspecting the batch-file, this is how it verifies the shell:

```
if /I "%CMDCMDLINE%" neq ""%COMSPEC%" " (
    echo.
    echo Please execute this script from inside a regular Windows command prompt.
    echo.
    exit /b 0
)
```

Even starting a new `cmd.exe` process won't do it.

Comment: Then just remove that part, which verifies shell, from `cntkpy34.bat` file. And if you can not edit that file, then just satisfy that condition with that PowerShell command: `$env:CMDCMDLINE=$env:COMSPEC`.

Comment: yeah, i would suggest doing just that ;)

Comment: @PetSerAl none of those are set on PS (they point to `cmd.exe` with no args) and I'm not sure that's safe because it has to activate an Anaconda environment. I'll try it anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Start-Process cmd -Argument "/c cntkpy34.bat" -RedirectStandardOutput somefile

This will open a new cmd window and run that there

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to capture the output?

Comment: Huh, the captured output still shows `Please execute this script from inside a regular Windows command prompt.`. This is one hard cookie.

Comment: this doesn't make sense, this is what is getting executed: ``C:\>if /I ""C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c 1.bat " NEQ ""C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" "``

Comment: That didn't solve my problem, but it is the answer to my question so I'll accept it anyway.

Comment: well, i'm sorry for that, but you could adjust the original bat file to include your powershell script invocation command, just like PetSerAI said